# Cassandra metrics- difference between latency to total latency

Tags: cassandra

I'm using Cassandra 2.2 and sending the Cassandra metrics to Graphite using pluggable metrics,

1. I've searched in org.apache.cassandra.metrics.ColumnFamily and saw there is an attribute "count" in ReadLatency and ReadTotalLatency,
   What is the difference between the 2 count attributes?
2. My main goal is to get the latency per read/write, how do you advise me to get it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

*org.apache.cassandra.metrics.ColumnFamily.ReadTotalLatency* is a [Counter](http://metrics.dropwizard.io/2.2.0/apidocs/com/yammer/metrics/core/Counter.html) which gives the sum of all read latencies.

*org.apache.cassandra.metrics.ColumnFamily.ReadLatency* is a [Timer](http://metrics.dropwizard.io/2.2.0/apidocs/com/yammer/metrics/core/Timer.html) which gives insights about how long the reads are taking, it reports attributes like *min*, *max*, *mean*, *75percentile*, *90percentile*, *99percentile*

for your purpose you should be using the *ReadLatency* and *Writelatency*

Comment: But ReadLatency also has a counter so why it is different from the counter in ReadTotalLatency? How can I get the latency per read (in the current moment) from ReadLatency if the attributes are cumulative?

Answer (score 0):

## Difference of 2 "count" attributes

`org.apache.cassandra.metrics.ColumnFamily.ReadTotalLatency` is a [Counter](http://metrics.dropwizard.io/2.2.0/apidocs/com/yammer/metrics/core/Counter.html).
Its "count" attribute provides the sum of all read latencies.

`org.apache.cassandra.metrics.ColumnFamily.ReadLatency` is a [Timer](http://metrics.dropwizard.io/2.2.0/apidocs/com/yammer/metrics/core/Timer.html).
Its "count" attribute provides the count of `Timer#update` calls.

## To get the *recent* latency per read/write

Use attributes like "min", "max", "mean", "75percentile", "90percentile", "99percentile".

Cassandra 2.2.7 uses `DecayingEstimatedHistogramReservoir` for Timer's reservoir, which makes recent values more significant.

Comment: Thanks, 1. So you say in Cassandra 2.2.7 the same Timer attributes are more tend to the recent values?  2. About the difference between the 2 count attributes, it seems that the sum of all read latencies equals to the count of Timer#update calls because every time there is a read action the Timer#update is called, so what is the difference?

Comment: For (1), yes. (might be interesting, https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-11752)

Comment: For (2), _the sum of all read latencies_ is not equal to _the count of Timer#update_. After calling totalLatencyCounter.inc(n) with n = 5 and 10, totalLatencyCounter.getCount() will return 15. After calling latencyTimer.update(n) with n = 5 and 10, latencyTimer.getCount() will return 2.

Comment: Ok I got it, Thanks coco!